# How to localize JOptionPane Message title?

Tags: java, localization

Is it possible to localize JOptionPane Message Title which is "Message"? I have localized Ok and Cancel buttons text using

```
UIManger.put("Ok","localtext");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't expect this answer...

Under you JDK installation directory, you will be able to find file named src.zip. Just unpack it and navigate to javax/swing/JOptionPane.java. It contains following method that might answer your question:

```
public static String showInputDialog(Component parentComponent,
    Object message) throws HeadlessException { 
    return showInputDialog(parentComponent, message, UIManager.getString(
        "OptionPane.inputDialogTitle", parentComponent), QUESTION_MESSAGE);
}
```

As you can see `OptionPane.inputDialogTitle` is probably what you were looking for... Although there is easier way to set title. However, if you are tempted to do everything the same way, you might just as well use UIManager.
I am writing this, because you would surely need this method for other dialogs, i.e. JFileChooser. And by doing so, you might find out that Desktop folder name is hard-coded in Java 6 on Windows Vista+ (it is resolved to actual folder name on disk, which is always "Desktop").

Comment: [Documentation for `UIManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html) for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the title for all dialogs of JOptionPane provides when you call the show*Dialog method.  It is usually the third method parameter.  For instance:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Component parentComponent, Object message, String title, int messageType)
```

Typically one reads the localized string (e.g. dialog title) from a resource bundle and passes it as argument to the show*Dialog call.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`java.util.ResourceBundle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)

With it, you store the localized values under specific keys in a `.properties` file, and then get them by: `ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale).get("messageKey")`.

`.properties` files are formed by having `basename_locale.properties`. For example, `messages_en.properties`

In regard to `JOptionPane`, [see here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#button) how to customize the texts. As for the title - you can pass it as an argument.

Comment: I don't think that was what Feras asked about :)

Comment: Why do you think so? I believe ResourceBundle is the standard for that, unlike using the UIManager

Comment: Really I don't mean this I mean localize strings in JDK

Comment: To some extent you are right, ResourceBundle is a standard way of externalizing string in Java. However, one need to use UIManager in order to translate Swing Dialogs into his language. This does not necessary mean hard-coding them.

Comment: @PawełDyda surely you don't need to use UIManager and it may not even be the correct way to do it. I went looking and found that the LAF classes use string resources like anyone else, so surely getting those translated and putting them on the classpath is more sensible and fits with the whole way things are supposed to work better than modifying the LAF.

Comment: @Tejkaz: I don't think that providing non-standard translations all the time is the most sensible approach. I had to disagree on this one. I prefer to use JVM-bundled translations for the sake of consistency. Surely, if there are no translations for given language, going `ResourceBundle` makes sense, but... I am not sure what's the current status of affairs, but in the days I wrote this answer the only way to truly localize things like `JFileChooser` was to mess up with `UIManager`.

Answer (score 0):

**Localizing JoptionPane Title, Message and options (YES, NO, OK, CANCEL):**

*Resource bundles allow us to set different languages. Bellow example illustrates how to create Message dialog with Chinese messages and options…*

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class LocalizeMessagePane {

    private static ResourceBundle resourceBundle = null;    
    //Language Property location
    private static final String PROPERTY_LOCATION = "resource"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        resourceBundle = getLanguageBundle(); //try to get Chinese bundle       

        // Get Yes/No option text from bundle

        Object[] options = { resourceBundle.getObject("Yes").toString(),
                             resourceBundle.getObject("No").toString() };

        int option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, resourceBundle
                .getObject("sureDo").toString(),                                
                resourceBundle.getObject("title").toString(),
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                options, options[1]);

        if(option==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
            // do stuff
        }       
    }   

    public static ResourceBundle getLanguageBundle() {
        try {
            /* The Property file should be placed under 'resource' directory. */
            resourceBundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(
                    new FileInputStream(PROPERTY_LOCATION
                            + "/Bundle_zh_CN.properties"),
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // do stuff
        }
        return resourceBundle;
    }
```